# Loading progress of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

How to calculate the loading site? I saw sites with status loading site, I know that there is an event `upload.onprogress XMLHttpRequest` to upload:

```
XMLHttpRequest.upload.onprogress = function(event) {
  console.log( 'Uploaded ' + event.loaded + ' / ' + event.total );
}
```

How to do the same, but to download (load) page/data from the server?

Answer (score 1):

There is an [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress) on MDN:

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

oReq.addEventListener("progress", updateProgress);
oReq.addEventListener("load", transferComplete);
oReq.addEventListener("error", transferFailed);
oReq.addEventListener("abort", transferCanceled);

oReq.open();

// ...

// progress on transfers from the server to the client (downloads)
function updateProgress (oEvent) {
  if (oEvent.lengthComputable) {
    var percentComplete = oEvent.loaded / oEvent.total;
    // ...
  } else {
    // Unable to compute progress information since the total size is unknown
  }
}

function transferComplete(evt) {
  console.log("The transfer is complete.");
}

function transferFailed(evt) {
  console.log("An error occurred while transferring the file.");
}

function transferCanceled(evt) {
  console.log("The transfer has been canceled by the user.");
}
```